# Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3.2 by Michael Hartl Chapter 9. authentication_pages_spec.rb doesn't see sign_in method in utilities.rb

Tags: railstutorial.org

This is my first question on StackOverflow, so bear with me ...

When I use the authentication_pages_spec.rb in [Listing 8.6](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#code-signin_success_tests) my tests pass.
Then I define the sign_in method in 'spec/support/utilities.rb' and modify authentication_pages_spec.rb according to [Listing 9.5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users?version=3.2#code-settings_link_test) and, when running

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb -e "Authentication"
```

I get

```
1) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: before { sign_in user }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x007fc585a87cd8>
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

for all the six tests under "with valid information".

It seems that the spec doesn't see the sign_in function and needs some declaration, anyhow I couldn't find where this is done in the Michael Hartl's code on Github.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I tried again today and now it works. I couldn't reproduce the error. Sorry for wasting your time, my kind reader.

Comment: The reason why was probably that when you add new content to the `support/utilities.rb` file, you have to restart your spork server (assuming you're using it).  Also, please either answer your own question or close this question so it doesn't come up in the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

Just Restart *spork* and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Hartl explains the `sign_in` helper almost immediately after that in [Listing 9.6](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users?version=3.2#code-sign_in_helper)

Comment: Prekash, thank you, but when I implement sign_in in utilities.rb and reference it in the spec, I get this NoMethodError.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same error messages, based on a subtle mis-placement of an end.  Sharing here, in case others run into the same test failures and are seeking a possible solution.

My mistake was in how I authored utilities.rb, which was:

```
include ApplicationHelper

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
    match do |page|
        page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')
end

def sign_in(user)
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
    # # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
    # cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    end
end
```

What the final `end` needs to be after the `RSpec::Matchers` block and should read like this:

```
include ApplicationHelper

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
    match do |page|
        page.should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid')
    end
end

def sign_in(user)
    visit signin_path
    fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"
    # # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
    # cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    end
```